# Webpack - output files

Tags: webpack

I'm having fun with webpack, but I've got strange thing.. I did a little config with youtube tutorial, and it works, but: in my dist folder I cant see generated app.css, why? Ps. Its tutorial with webpack2

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
    var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    var path = require("path");

    module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js',
        contact: './src/contact.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.scss$/, 
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                    allChunks: true
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer:{
     contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
     compress: true,
     port: 9000,
     stats: "errors-only",
     open: true
    },
     plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'fsdfsdfsdfsdf',
            hash: true, // ważne dla bezpieczeństwa
            excludeChunks: ['contact'],
            template: './src/index.html' // Load a custom template (lodash by default see the FAQ for details)
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'fsdfsdfsdfsdf',
            hash: true,
            chunks: ['contact'],
            filename: 'contact.html',
            template: './src/contact.html'
            }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                filename: 'app.css'
            })
     ]
    }
```

I've got in extract text plugin name, and I had publicPath, but in W3 its not supported i guess.

Comment: "I'm having fun with webpack" - you may be the first ;)

Comment: Hmm it works honestly now. I dont know it's so strange to build a simple page with angularjs, bootstrap and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack needs an `entry` point from where it builds dependency graph and then processes/bundles all that is in the graph.

While your webpack config has **everything in place** to process the sass files, the source code must be missing to specify the dependency. Its typically done with `require("some.scss")` where its required.

From your last comment its not clear if you figured out the issue. If not hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, yep it works when i added require, thanks for clearly answer ;)